# Quadratic programming

Tags: quadratic-programming

For a research project I am interested in minimizing $x^TQx$ under the constraints $Qx \le b$, where $Q$ is a positive definite matrix and $b$ is a vector of negative elements.  I have solved this with the Gurobi Solver, but as the matrix $Q$ is not sparse, there are lots of terms in the objective.  I was wondering if one can take advantage of the constraints being so closely related to the objective.

Comment: Well, setting $y=Q^{\frac{1}{2}}x$ one can minimize $y^Ty$ under the constraints $Q^{\frac{1}{2}}y \le b$.  Any better ideas?